# End result does not have a mask

Tags: rendering

I Was watching "How to make a Lightsaber in Blender | The easy way" where it taught me how to make a lightsaber using a mask. Towards the end of the video,I clicked render animation and when i checked my output file, the pictures had no mask around them.
**I used a image sequence.**

My render result is this[image]

Comment: At the bottom where it has the checkbox for background, there is a "Use Nodes" checkbox to the left of it.

Comment: I have already checked the "use nodes" checkbox.

Comment: I added a Full picture of my blender screen.

Comment: Do you mean the checkbox in the picture above.
     
I think it is renderable

Comment: Yeah, looks good, IDK what your problem is then. What does the backdrop look like?

Comment: what version of blender do u use

Comment: In render settings under post processing is compositing enabled? You may need to share your blend for someone to find the issue, upload to [blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) and add the link here is the preferred way.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions:

1. Make sure you have your mask selected from the drop-down in the Mask node
2. Make sure your output is not only connected to the Viewer node but also to the Composite node output. Ensure that "Use Nodes" at the bottom of the Node editor is checked.
3. Make sure the mask layer you are using is enabled to render

Please update with more information if this does not solve your problem.

Comment: The weird part is I can clearly see my blade in the node editor. And what do you mean by "Make sure your output is not only connected to the Viewer node but also to the Composite node output. Ensure that "Use Nodes" at the bottom of the Node editor is checked."

Comment: @CharanKotha In the Node Editor, you will see the backdrop that is connected to the "Viewer" node at the end of your tree. For your nodes to be rendered, you must connect this same output to a "Composite" node. If you don't have one, add one with Shift + A > Output > Composite.

Comment: That is how my node editor looks like, but i just turned off the backdrop.

Comment: "Make sure the mask layer you are using is enabled to render" How do I do this.

Comment: What do you mean by "Make sure the mask layer you are using is enabled to render".

Comment: @CharanKotha See this image: https://wiki.blender.org/uploads/thumb/8/83/Blender2.64_mask_editor_overview.png/600px-Blender2.64_mask_editor_overview.png

On the right side with the layers, there is a camera you can click and unclick. Make sure it is render-able.

Comment: Do you mean the checkbox in the picture above.

Comment: I think it is renderable.