# How to enable a Mask layer to render

Tags: rendering

I need help understanding what this means "Make sure the mask layer you are using is enabled to render" the person who is helping in an another problem said this.
What does this mean?

The link to the the other blender problem I have.[End result does not have a mask](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84902/end-result-does-not-have-a-mask).

Comment: Out of context it is hard to say. Seems to be related to Render Layers, so make sure your render layers are active in the *Properties Window*

Comment: It's best to provide screenshots to show what setup do you have and what the question is. Maybe that's about [render layers used as mask layers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/post_process/layers.html#layer-panel) when you include in the enabled buttons in the Mask group present in the Scene group.